# What is a safe number of triangles/vertexes for a WebGL scene?

Tags: javascript, html, memory-management, webgl

What can be considered a safe number of triangles/vertexes for a WebGL application to work on recent desktop/notebook machines (say, bought 2009 or after)? I'm worried about memory, not performance. The more vertexes I can send to WebGL, the better looking the scene will be. For some scenes, it would be nice if I could send 30k triangles (some 60k vertexes, due use of triangle strips).

Doing a quick calculation, 60k vertexes means a 60k x vec4, where each vec4 is 4 x 8 bytes (8 because I'm considering a double for each component). So that gives about 1.9mb of vertex memory. Is that safe for most recent WebGL environments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be ok but i more concern about webgl sandboxing limitations. For example Flash has limited amount of buffers and their size, shader instruction amount, only 4 (or 5) render contexts etc. and most likely memory.  WebGL much less restrictive but implementation is 1. Browser dependant 2. machine dependant (Google Chrome can run WebGL on DirectX  "[angle project](http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/)") If browser doesn't has DirectX fallback and  machine hasn't proper OpenGL drivers WebGL wont work.   Also there was issues with different implementation of [same origins policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for textures.  So you can't just hope that your app will work on any machine. You can't avoid benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

You should be safe, no problem. I'm working on a MacBook from 2009 and haven't experienced any memory problems (but a lot of performance issues) at all. And I've had scenes that use far more memory than that.